# Как имитировать тормозной браузер, искажающий JS timeout / interval?

Tags: javascript, таймер

Пишу таймер, который тикает раз в секунду, и должен это делать с точностью до 1/200 секунды. Даже если браузер тупит и комп слабый.

Поэтому ориентируюсь не на `setTimeout( func, 1000)`, а на более частые вызовы и системное время в миллисекундах.

**Вопрос – как тестировать?** Надо как-то имитировать разную степень тормознутости системы, чтобы оценить поведение скрипта в разных условиях. И записывать в консоль отклонения в миллисекундах от идеального времени каждого тика.

---

**Upd.** В этом алгоритме я внутри каждой секунды несколько раз запускаю setTimeout() на время, меньшее 1000, и зависящее от расхождения фактического и ожидаемого времени очередного запуска, и времени оставшегося до «конца» секунды.

Гипотеза: тормоза системы не меняются *значительно* в «окне» одной секунды. Тогда, выполнив несколько коротких (200-500ms) предварительных `setTimeout()`, можно чуть правильнее предположить лаг следующего, и точнее попасть в нужное время

**Upd. 2** нашёл [интересный совет](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8521733/556876) – тестировать в виртуальной машине, в которой урезать ресурсы.

Answer (score 2):

```
!function() {
  var delta = 100; // Интервал будет плюс-минус 100 милисекунд
  var ost = setTimeout
  setTimeout = function(f, time) {
    time += (Math.random() * 2 - 1) * delta
    ost(f, time)
  }
}()
```

Но, вообще говоря, ваше решение довольно странное. Более частые вызовы приведут лишь к большей загрузки и так тормознутой системы, и не помогут отмерить интервалы точнее.

Браузер же "тупит" не просто так - а потому что процессор занят чем-то еще. И если в некоторый момент времени процессор занят - то скрипт проснется невовремя независимо от того, на 20 миллисекунд скрипт засыпал или на 1000.

Comment: Я хочу отладить алгоритм, минимизирующий ошибки по времени при загруженной системе. Т.е. мне нужно не случайные таймауты заряжать, а именно один и тот же скрипт запускать на по-разному задумчивых системах в рамках теста. В этом алгоритме я внутри каждой секунды несколько раз запускаю `setTimeout()` на время, меньшее 1000, и зависящее от расхождения фактического и ожидаемого времени очередного запуска, и времени оставшегося до «конца» секунды.

Comment: Вот есть NTP и [алгоритм Марзулло](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%BE) (подробно не копал пока) – но ведь этот протокол справляется со случайными задержками в сети при синхронизации времени. Правда, там от нескольких «шумных» источников берутся данные, а в JS один таймер. Хочу что-то функционально подобное реализовать на JS для неточных timeout'ов. Может, несколько параллельных тредов таймеров пускать.

Comment: @Sergiks, NTP *определяет* текущее время, вы же пытаетесь *дождаться* нужного момента. Это совершенно разные задачи, и вторая - в общем случае невозможна если только не в RTOS работаете.

Comment: Моя гипотеза, что тормоза системы не меняются в «окне» одной секунды значительно. Тогда, выполнив несколько коротких (200-500ms) setTimeout'ов, можно чуть правильнее предположить лаг следующего, и точнее попасть в нужное время.

Comment: @Sergiks странное предположение. Впрочем, вы сами все увидите...

Answer (score 2):

Возможно вам стоит загрузить систему параллельно дополнительными вычислениями на основе тех же таумаутов. Например что-то вроде этого

```
function noise() {
    var count = Math.random() * 1000000; // какая-то нагрузка
    for(var i=0;i<count;i++)
    {
        var tmp = Math.random(); // просто для нагрузки
    }
    var time = Math.random() * 100; // не реже чем раз в 100 милллисекунд           
    setTimeout(noise, time); // и снова 
}
```

Подобрав параметры (верхние границы) и способ вычиления (можно какую-нибудь функцию математическую, например по синусоиде) для  `time` и `count` (а также операции в цикле) можно увеличить или уменьшить фоновую нагрузку, что должно привести к замедлению работы браузера, ИМХО.

Comment: Это, выходит, блокирующая загрузка. Либо её надо запускать отдельным процессом – что непредсказуемо провалит скорость тестируемого треда, если вообще повлияет. 

Может, как-то можно загрузить процесс этого же инстанса браузерного и JS движка, не вмешиваясь в логику самого JS?

Comment: @Sergiks других идей у меня особо нет. В принципе, тестирование в виртуальной машине действительно неплохой вариант. Также можно просто загрузить всю систему без применения виртуальной машины - наиболее эффективно это будет при создании 10+ потоков в любой запущенной программе (не на js, а например на C++), то есть сделать свой комп тормознутым.

Answer (score -1):

Если на браузере chrome переключиться в режим просмотр кода (инспектор), переходите в режим телефона/планшета и выбираете скорость 50 КВ/s.
Тормоза обеспечены. 
Скриншот с красными стрелками http://prnt.sc/8x4el4

Comment: Это не я вас минусовал. Но ответ не верный – та вкладка имитирует *медленную загрузку* страницы и скриптов. А надо имитировать **медленную работу** браузера с уже загруженной страницей.